# PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel

1. PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
   Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\moda\storage\framework/sessions/b5fb0faa67ead409945cfb4735d91ce401e933ef): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

upload server .env & database connection path right but sill error.
Error database how to solve this problem

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Check your host either it is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`